# What are these fancy TypeVar's PyCharm generates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generics, type-hinting

I want to implement a generic dictionary mapping textual keys to classes being or inheriting from `MyConstrainingClass`, so I declared a `TypeVar` and `MyDict` class as follows:

```
from typing import Mapping, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", MyConstrainingClass)


class MyDict(Mapping[str, T]):
```

When I accept PyCharm's suggestion to implement the abstract base class methods, it generates the following output:

```
class MyList(Mapping[str, T]):
    def __getitem__(self, k: _KT) -> _VT_co:
        pass

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[_T_co]:
        pass

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        pass
```

What are those `_KT`, `_VT_co`, `_T_co` generic type vars? I haven't defined them myself anywhere, it seems to have taken them from the super class.

Apparently they describe "KeyType", "ValueType covariant" and "Type (?) covariant", but I have no clue if I have to create such generic parameters in my case at all or how to define them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PyCharm is taking them from the [`Mapping` declaration in the `typing` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/typing.py#L1824-L1826) (or their own internal version of the file):

```
class Mapping(Collection[KT], Generic[KT, VT_co],
              extra=collections_abc.Mapping):
    __slots__ = ()
```

(with the `T_co` covariant inherited from further up the base classes, from `Iterable`).

I'd replace those suggestions with your more concrete versions:

```
class MyList(Mapping[str, T]):
    def __getitem__(self, k: str) -> T:
        pass

    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator[str]:
        pass

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense to me. I was worrying I had to create some covariant `TypeVar`s to meet what the `typing` module defines.